# Understanding of Tangent Plane in R3

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Given a sphere $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2=9$, steps to find the equation of the tangent plane to this sphere at point (1,-1,1) are as follows:

$$(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2=9$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2-9=0$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2-9=f(x,y,z)$$

$$\nabla f(1,-1,1)=(-2,-4,4) $$
$$f_x(1,-1,1)(x-1)+f_y(1,-1,1)(y+1)+f_z(1,-1,1)(z-1)=0$$

When setting the equation of the sphere to 0, then setting the equation equal to a fourth variable, $f$ is not a sphere anymore.

If the sphere equation is altered in this way, how does the partial derivatives of $f$ associate back to the sphere in that they are apart of the tangent plane equation for the sphere???

Comment: What do you mean by the fourth variable? It seems to me that you mistakenly assume that $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2-9=f(x,y,z)$ is yet another expression of the equation of the sphere. In fact, this is the definition of the function $f$ we're introducing here. In terms of $f$, the equation of the sphere is simply $f(x,y,z) = 0$.

Comment: Ohh I see, when $f(x,y,z)=0$ it is the equivalent to the sphere, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the tangent plane is:
$$-2(x-1)-4(y+1)+4(z+1)=0 \implies x+2y-2z=1.$$